# Conda is only showing the input() prompt after giving input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a very easy input statement in Python:

```
sentence = input("Please give a sentence: ")
print("Your sentence is:\n" + sentence)
```

When I run the code in the integrated terminal of Visual Studio Code, it does not display the prompt message but directly takes an input. When the input is given, the prompt message is printed in front of the `print()` statement:

```
Hey
Please give a sentence: Your sentence is:
Hey
```

I've already installed the second-to-last version of the Python extension in VS code, but that does not work.

Comment: conda is a dependency/environment manager. The anaconda distribution is just the regular CPython distribution with additional third-party libraries. In any case, this looks like some issue wiht visual-studio code.

Comment: What happens when you run it from a standard terminal? (Windows CMD, Powershell, bash, ....)

Comment: @RiceKab It works, then. But it's more easier to use the integrated terminal obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stemmed from the Python extension using `conda run`. That has since been reverted and so everything should now work.